# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms

here is the Complete Exception Detail

```
   {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC (System.Int32 rc, SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db) [0x00067] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00282] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00007] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00011] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.DbCommandMethod executeMethod, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameterValues, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00358] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000a0] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00152] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext _, System.ValueTuple`2[T1,T2] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00220] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] entriesToSave, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00088] in <adf771f92e754fe1bb85c5850cd0c16b>:0 
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync (System.Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f8] in <adf771f92e754fe1bb85c5850cd0c16b>:0 
      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync (System.Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000e9] in <adf771f92e754fe1bb85c5850cd0c16b>:0 
      at Mobile.ViewModel.OrdersDetailViewModel.DatabaseAttachmentOpertaions () [0x00369]
```

some time produce this exception

```
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: fileAttachments._id'.
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC (System.Int32 rc, SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db) [0x00067] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00282] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00007] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00011] in <b46e232ade014524baa458345f270c50>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.DbCommandMethod executeMethod, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameterValues, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00358] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000a0] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00152] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext _, System.ValueTuple`2[T1,T2] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00220] in <69f795dffc844780bfcfff4ff8415a92>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] entriesToSave, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00088] in <adf771f92e754fe1bb85c5850cd0c16b>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync (System.Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f8] in <adf771f92e754fe1bb85c5850cd0c16b>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync (System.Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000e9] in <adf771f92e754fe1bb85c5850cd0c16b>:0
```

I have these are the two models and when i Update the Model this Exception is failed .
 i have uploaded the picture1 then i called saveChanges then this exception is raised

```
  [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid UniqueID { get { return _UniqueID; } set { _UniqueID = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => UniqueID); } }

        private int _ID = 0;
        public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ID); } }

        private string _TreetraceOrderNumber = "";
        public string TreetraceOrderNumber { get { return _TreetraceOrderNumber; } set { _TreetraceOrderNumber = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceOrderNumber); } }

        private DateTime? _TreetraceOrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime TreetraceOrderDate { get { return (DateTime)_TreetraceOrderDate; } set { _TreetraceOrderDate = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceOrderDate); } }

        private string _SupplierId = "";
        public string SupplierId { get { return _SupplierId; } set { _SupplierId = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SupplierId); } }
        [NotMapped]
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

        private string _Afdeling = "";
        public string Afdeling { get { return _Afdeling; } set { _Afdeling = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Afdeling); } }

        private string _TreetraceStatus = "";
        public string TreetraceStatus { get { return _TreetraceStatus; } set { _TreetraceStatus = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceStatus); } }

        private bool _Attachments = false;
        public bool Attachments { get { return _Attachments; } set { _Attachments = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Attachments); } }

        private bool _SyncAttachment = false;
        public bool SyncAttachment { get { return _SyncAttachment; } set { _SyncAttachment = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SyncAttachment); } }

        private bool? _TreetraceIsIrrelevant = false;
        public bool? TreetraceIsIrrelevant { get { return _TreetraceIsIrrelevant; } set { if (value == null) { _TreetraceIsIrrelevant = false; } else { _TreetraceIsIrrelevant = value; } RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceIsIrrelevant); } }

        private string _TreetraceComments = "";
        public string TreetraceComments { get { return _TreetraceComments; } set { _TreetraceComments = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceComments); } }

        private string _fileName = string.Empty;
        public string fileName { get { return _fileName; } set { _fileName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => fileName); } }

        private string _fileNumber = string.Empty;
        public string fileNumber { get { return _fileNumber; } set { _fileNumber = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => fileNumber); } }

        private string _TreetraceHighestStatusLine = "";
        public string TreetraceHighestStatusLine { get { return _TreetraceHighestStatusLine; } set { _TreetraceHighestStatusLine = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceHighestStatusLine); } }

        private string _TreeTraceSupplierName = "";
        public string TreeTraceSupplierName { get { return _TreeTraceSupplierName; } set { _TreeTraceSupplierName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreeTraceSupplierName); } }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        private string _UpdatedByApp = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedByApp { get { return _UpdatedByApp; } set { _UpdatedByApp = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }
        private string _UpdatedByOS = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedByOS { get { return _UpdatedByOS; } set { _UpdatedByOS = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdatedByOSVersion = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedByOSVersion { get { return _UpdatedByOSVersion; } set { _UpdatedByOSVersion = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdateByAppVersionName = string.Empty;
        public string UpdateByAppVersionName { get { return _UpdateByAppVersionName; } set { _UpdateByAppVersionName = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdateByAppVersionNumber = string.Empty;
        public string UpdateByAppVersionNumber { get { return _UpdateByAppVersionNumber; } set { _UpdateByAppVersionNumber = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdatedByNetworkType = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedByNetworkType { get { return _UpdatedByNetworkType; } set { _UpdatedByNetworkType = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdatedByManufacturer = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedByManufacturer { get { return _UpdatedByManufacturer; } set { _UpdatedByManufacturer = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdatedByModel = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedByModel { get { return _UpdatedByModel; } set { _UpdatedByModel = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _DeviceTypeCreatedBy = string.Empty;
        public string DeviceTypeCreatedBy { get { return _DeviceTypeCreatedBy; } set { _DeviceTypeCreatedBy = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _DeviceTypeUpdatedBy = string.Empty;
        public string DeviceTypeUpdatedBy { get { return _DeviceTypeUpdatedBy; } set { _DeviceTypeUpdatedBy = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdatedLongitude = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedLongitude { get { return _UpdatedLongitude; } set { _UpdatedLongitude = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }

        private string _UpdatedLatitude = string.Empty;
        public string UpdatedLatitude { get { return _UpdatedLatitude; } set { _UpdatedLatitude = value; /*RaisePropertyChanged(() => SGDDDepRegion);*/ } }


        //private string _Picture1Blobbed = "";
        //public string Picture1Blobbed { get { return _Picture1Blobbed; } set { _Picture1Blobbed = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Picture1Blobbed); } }
        //private string _Picture2Blobbed = "";
        //public string Picture2Blobbed { get { return _Picture2Blobbed; } set { _Picture2Blobbed = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Picture2Blobbed); } }
        //private string _Picture3Blobbed = "";
        //public string Picture3Blobbed { get { return _Picture3Blobbed; } set { _Picture3Blobbed = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Picture3Blobbed); } }
        //private string _Picture4Blobbed = "";
        //public string Picture4Blobbed { get { return _Picture4Blobbed; } set { _Picture4Blobbed = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Picture4Blobbed); } }

        [NotMapped]

        public List<FileAttachment> OtherDocuments { get; set; }


        //private FileAttachment _fileAttachment = null;
        ////[OneToMany]
        //public FileAttachment FileAttachment { get { return _fileAttachment; } set { _fileAttachment = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => FileAttachment); } }

        private List<FileAttachment> _fileAttachments = null;
        [InverseProperty("ordersModel")]
        public List<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get { return _fileAttachments; } set { _fileAttachments = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => FileAttachments); } }

        private FileAttachment _Picture1 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment Picture1 { get { return _Picture1; } set { _Picture1 = value; } }

        private FileAttachment _Picture2 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment Picture2 { get { return _Picture2; } set { _Picture2 = value; } }

        private FileAttachment _Picture3 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment Picture3 { get { return _Picture3; } set { _Picture3 = value; } }

        private FileAttachment _Picture4 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment Picture4 { get { return _Picture4; } set { _Picture4 = value; } }

        private FileAttachment _compressedPicture1 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment CompressedPicture1 { get { return _compressedPicture1; } set { _compressedPicture1 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CompressedPicture1); } }

        private FileAttachment _compressedPicture2 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment CompressedPicture2 { get { return _compressedPicture2; } set { _compressedPicture2 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CompressedPicture2); } }

        private FileAttachment _compressedPicture3 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment CompressedPicture3 { get { return _compressedPicture3; } set { _compressedPicture3 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CompressedPicture3); } }

        private FileAttachment _compressedPicture4 = null;
        [NotMapped]
        public FileAttachment CompressedPicture4 { get { return _compressedPicture4; } set { _compressedPicture4 = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CompressedPicture4); } }
```

And This is the Second Model I didn't finding the issue where I am making  wrong.  I have Use Foreignkey and Inverse property to make relation ship between them

```
[Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public byte[] base64 { get; set; }
        public long filesize { get; set; }
        public string filetype { get; set; }
        //[Ignore]
        //public MediaFile stream { get; set; }

        private Guid _OrderID = Guid.NewGuid();
        [ForeignKey("OrderID")]
        public Guid OrderID { get { return _OrderID; } set { _OrderID = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => OrderID); } }
        public OrdersModel  ordersModel { get; set; }


        private string _TreetraceOrderNumber = "";
        public string TreetraceOrderNumber { get { return _TreetraceOrderNumber; } set { _TreetraceOrderNumber = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TreetraceOrderNumber); } }
```

Here Im updating the table.

```
List<Model.FileAttachment> itemsToDelete =  App.dbContext.fileAttachments.Where(x => x.OrderID == Model.UniqueID || x.TreetraceOrderNumber == Model.TreetraceOrderNumber).ToList();
                if (itemsToDelete.Count > 0)
                {
                    App.dbContext.fileAttachments.RemoveRange(itemsToDelete);
                    await App.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                    //await App.dbContext.DeleteAllAsync(itemsToDelete);
                if (Model.TreetraceStatus == Config.CompletedStatus && Model.FileAttachments != null && Model.FileAttachments.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var OrdrNr in Model.FileAttachments)
                    {
                        OrdrNr.TreetraceOrderNumber = Model.TreetraceOrderNumber;

                    }
                    App.dbContext.fileAttachments.UpdateRange(Model.FileAttachments);
                    await App.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                    var tracking = App.dbContext.ordersModels.Update(Model);

                    await App.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    var isModified = tracking.State == EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: can you share code, which you write to update model?

Comment: Check now Updated the code

Comment: Why you have for loop when you are already saving all FileAttachments at once. Also when you are doing UpdateRange, you are passing Model in it, not sure what is type of model, irrespective of that you are not assigning foreighn key value , I assume you have to set orderId which you generated in previous step in for loop. Can you descirbe logic what you are trying to do as code is not really descriptive.

Comment: I have all ready  data added into table.when user go to existing record and add picture in it .then the record updated in database

Comment: user can add multiple pictures

Comment: like picture 1 and picture 2 and so on

Comment: What is type of orderModels and type of model. i think you need to select one record which you want to update amd modify that and then call save method. Update range will update all records in table.

Comment: orderModels is Table name

Comment: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: this exception is producing .i have updated update code

Comment: Looks like your code to update is not correct ,look in to some blog on how to update record in ef.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196551/discussion-between-krunal-parmar-and-zubairz).

Comment: that's great. You can put in answer what worked for you.